# Determinant inequality involving Hermitian, positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, determinants

Let $A,B,C\in M_{n}(\mathbb C)$ be Hermitian and positive-definite matrices such that $A+B+C=I_{n}$.
Show that
$$\det\left(6(A^3+B^3+C^3)+I_{n}\right)\ge 5^n\det(A^2+B^2+C^2)$$

This question has been [asked on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860294/how-prove-this-matrix-inequality-det-left6a3b3c3i-n-right-ge-5n-d) without receiving any answers. Just some comment by [achille hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui) and myself.
I think this result is true because for $n=1$ we have  $6(A^3+B^3+C^3)+1\ge 5(A^2+B^2+C^2)$
but unfortunately I didn't succeed to generalize for $n\ge2$.

N.B.: My apologize if this question is not suitable on math overflow.

Comment: Why do your expect this to be true? Have you compiled extensive evidence or is this posed somewhere as a problem?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy You can look at the link on MSE, it's a problem but achille hui was thinking that perhaps this problem is false, but as I said for $n=1$ is true because we can prove that $6(A^3+B^3+C^3)+I_n\ge 5(A^2+B^2+C^2)$ with proviso that $A+B+C=I_n$.

Comment: This corollary of Jensen's inequality might be useful if you want to try to show that $6(A^3+B^3+C^3)+I\geq5(A^2+B^2+C^2)$: If $A$ is a positive definite hermitean matrix, $x$ a unit vector and $0\leq m\leq M$, then $(x^TA^Mx)^m\geq(x^TA^mx)^M$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Sigh. That particular OP posts question after question from contests, mostly in China but not always. I continue to think that the best approach is to get the OP to get the answers from the contest organizers, which are typically published eventually.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, sure. I find many contest problems fascinating. I do think people should be aware that this is a contest problem, someone knows the answer very well, and the person who originally asked on MSE does not care very much about it, there seems to be a bit of compulsion involved. Meanwhile, if I remain the only vote to close, there will be plenty of time for answers to appear here; also answers can be posted at MSE any time regardless. It is probably fair to say that I dislike the machine-gun rapid-fire postings more than I dislike contest problems.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Personally, I really don't want people to ask contest questions here if they are sitting those contests, or supposed to be practising for those contests.

Comment: @YemonChoi, this one is in the middle, as the person asking here is not the same as the one who first asked on MSE

Comment: @WillJagy But what if that OP doesn't get access to the solutions?

Comment: There is some evidence for the validity @MichaelRenardy , and [even a partial result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3513457/316749) on math.SE if one additionally assumes
$$\|A-\tfrac13\mathbb 1\|\,,\,\|B-\tfrac13\mathbb 1\|\,,\,
\|C-\tfrac13\mathbb 1\|\:\leqslant\:\tfrac16$$
which means to consider matrix perturbations of the symmetry point
$A=B=C=\tfrac13\mathbb 1$.